# extract values of specific columns from dataframe to insert to a new dataframe row by row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

i have a dataframe, namely data, with a datetime index and the below columns :

```
                                id  activity     x          y           z
datetime                    
1970-01-01 00:42:00.219142823   1623    A   -0.152512   -8.585220   -1.219192
1970-01-01 00:42:00.269496827   1623    A   0.999466    -8.196548   -0.758926
1970-01-01 00:42:00.319850830   1623    A   0.450241    -8.701187   -1.290024
1970-01-01 00:42:00.370204834   1623    A   -0.042175   -9.739563   -1.787415
1970-01-01 00:42:00.420558838   1623    A   3.551483    -10.745132  -1.266403
... ... ... ... ... ...
1970-01-22 01:26:29.872699000   1644    A   2.239343    -8.408914   2.074087
1970-01-22 01:26:29.892898000   1644    A   2.548301    -8.157437   1.820215
1970-01-22 01:26:29.912994000   1644    A   2.636917    -7.786209   2.057322
1970-01-22 01:26:29.933195000   1644    A   2.545906    -7.743098   1.801055
1970-01-22 01:26:29.953291000   1644    A   2.373464    -8.071217   1.585503
279817 rows × 5 columns
```

every 119 rows i want to extract only the values of x, y, z columns, as well with the activity label, and put them in a new dataframe row by row. the values of each column followed up by the next column. like below :

```
values of column x|values of column y|values of column z|activity
```

next row after 119 rows of values of the dataframe data

```
values of column x|values of column y|values of column z|activity
```

etc

any ideas would be very helpful and much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: what's special about 119 rows?

Comment: it's time intervals based on the datetime index. every 119 rows are 5 sec of continuous data. the first minute doesn't count cause it's not whole 60 sec.

Comment: ah, but then you can say so: "every 5 seconds" -- that's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame is called `data`, then you can use

```
data.iloc[::119, [data.columns.get_loc(col) for col in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'activity']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: after understanding that the question is really about getting data every 5 seconds, we can say so more directly:

```py
wanted = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'activity']
newdf = df.resample('5s', origin='start').first()[wanted].copy()
```

Note: look at the various possibilities for the `origin` argument. Using `'start'` means we start with the first index in `df`. But usually it is more natural to used the default (`'start_day'`) which makes "round datetimes".

---

Original answer:

```py
newdf = df.iloc[::119][['x', 'y', 'z', 'activity']].copy()
```

Example (**reproducible setup**):

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
n = 279817
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.linspace(1623, 1644, n).round().astype(int),
    'activity': ['A'] * n,
}, index=pd.date_range(start='1970-01-01 00:42:00', end='1970-01-22 01:26:30', periods=n))
df[list('xyz')] = np.random.normal(size=(n, 3))

# code above, then

>>> newdf
                                      x         y         z activity
1970-01-01 00:42:00.000000000  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738        A
1970-01-01 00:54:52.762565400 -0.477974 -0.479656  0.620358        A
1970-01-01 01:07:45.525130800  1.327783 -0.101281 -0.803141        A
1970-01-01 01:20:38.287696200 -1.429991 -0.061638 -1.432735        A
1970-01-01 01:33:31.050261600 -1.109478 -0.547518  0.665967        A
...                                 ...       ...       ...      ...
1970-01-22 00:29:53.740994081 -0.267150  0.414945 -0.627917        A
1970-01-22 00:42:46.503559481 -0.001320  0.743854  0.137284        A
1970-01-22 00:55:39.266124882 -0.469361 -1.204360 -1.688222        A
1970-01-22 01:08:32.028690282  0.340768 -0.911023  0.069327        A
1970-01-22 01:21:24.791255682 -1.461045  1.938692 -0.188877        A

[2352 rows x 4 columns]
```